# Common IoT connectivity to GCP, AWS, Azure, etc

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, google-cloud-platform, architecture, cloud

I've to extend an existing product based on ARM-Cortex M0 and M4 micro-controller (No RTOS-bare metal event loop) to enable IoT capabilities.
I'm using W5500 Hardwired TCP/IP embedded Ethernet controller to enable internet connection for my micro-controllers.
One of the requirement of the project is that it must have cloud connectivity (using MQTT and/or ReST API) with all major vendors i.e. Google Cloud Platform, Amazon Web Services, Microsoft Azure and optional cloud providers like Linode and Digital Ocean.
The cloud connectivity is decided by client during installation.
As these devices are field configurable, connectivity to all these platforms need to be built-in the devices.
While I was scouring over internet regarding this topic, I found out that GCP have their own set of libraries and so do AWS and Azure.
[Google Cloud IoT Device SDK for Embedded C](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/iot-device-sdk-embedded-c)
[AWS IoT Device SDK for Embedded C](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C)
[Azure SDK for Embedded C](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-c)
I was under assumption that either by using simple MQTT and/or ReST API I would be able to communicate with any cloud service. **Is my assumption wrong?**
Is their any additional communication mechanism/layer that has been introduced over MQTT or ReST API to communicate with these cloud services that warrant need of such explicit libraries.
What are my options here to interface with all these services?
Can I use GCP MQTT library to communicate with AWS or Azure or vice versa?
Can I use [Wiznet IO Library's](https://github.com/Wiznet/ioLibrary_Driver) MQTT client to connect to either of these services.

Comment: Are you trying to register your device to IoT core in GCP?

Comment: @SakshiGatyan, Yes. I will be registering my device to IoT core.

Comment: Could you refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/mqtt-bridge) which uses MQTT to communicate with Cloud IoT Core?

Comment: @SakshiGatyan, I had looked into the documentation. It is my understanding that the above mentioned documentation needs google-cloud-cpp. Am I right regarding this or it can work on any mqtt client.

Comment: Yes as in the document, you'll have to use the mentioned client libraries to configure MQTT client.